# How can I extract only subject:result from this string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

So I wrote a code to grab my exam results when it's released on the website. But I can't figure out how to output results in a subjectName:subjectResults format.

My output is something like this,

> Results found b'{"examination":"G.C.E. (O/L)
>   EXAMINATION","year":"2018","name":"NANAYAKKARA IGALA ARACHCHIGE
>   NAVINDU THARUKA
>   PERERA","indexNo":"80299920","nic":null,"districtRank":null,"islandRank":null,"marks":null,"status":null,"zScore":null,"stream":null,"subjectResults":[{"subjectName":"BUDDHISM","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"SINHALA
>   LANGUAGE & LITT.","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"ENGLISH
>   LANGUAGE","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"MATHEMATICS","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"HISTORY","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"SCIENCE","subjectResult":"B"},{"subjectName":"DRAMA
>   & THEATRE(SINHALA)","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"BUSINESS &
>   ACCT. STUDIES","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"INFOR. & COMM.
>   TECHNOLOGY","subjectResult":"A"}],"studentInfo":[{"param":"Examination","value":"G.C.E.
>   (O/L)
>   EXAMINATION"},{"param":"Year","value":"2018"},{"param":"Name","value":"NANAYAKKARA
>   IGALA ARACHCHIGE NAVINDU THARUKA PERERA"},{"param":"Index
>   Number","value":"80299920"},{"param":"NIC Number","value":""}]}'

I need just the subjects and their results listed line by line.

Here's my script

```
import requests
import re
import time



index_number = "80299920"

URL = f'https://result.doenets.lk/result/service/OlResult?index={index_number}&nic='

while True:
    try:
        req = requests.get(URL)
        x = req.content.decode('utf-8')
        search = re.findall(r'\"subjectResults\":\[]', x)
        if search:
            print("No results yet")
            time.sleep(0.001)
            continue
        else:
            print("Results found")
            res = requests.get(f'https://result.doenets.lk/result/service/OlResult?index={index_number}&nic=')
            results=res.content
            print(results)
            exit()
    except Exception:
        print("ok")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is `JSON` format, so you may parse it and use it as python `dict`

```
res = requests.get(...)
result = res.get_json() # or result = json.loads(res.text)

for item in result['subjectResults']:
    print(item['subjectName'] + ":" + item['subjectResult'])

# Printing

BUDDHISM:A
SINHALA LANGUAGE & LITT.:A
ENGLISH LANGUAGE:A
MATHEMATICS:A
HISTORY:A
SCIENCE:B
DRAMA & THEATRE(SINHALA):A
BUSINESS & ACCT. STUDIES:A
INFOR. & COMM. TECHNOLOGY:A
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string is a json, so you can load it as a python dict and iterate through your results.

```
   import json

results = b'{"examination":"G.C.E. (O/L) EXAMINATION","year":"2018","name":"NANAYAKKARA IGALA ARACHCHIGE NAVINDU THARUKA PERERA","indexNo":"80299920","nic":null,"districtRank":null,"islandRank":null,"marks":null,"status":null,"zScore":null,"stream":null,"subjectResults":[{"subjectName":"BUDDHISM","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"SINHALA LANGUAGE & LITT.","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"ENGLISH LANGUAGE","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"MATHEMATICS","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"HISTORY","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"SCIENCE","subjectResult":"B"},{"subjectName":"DRAMA & THEATRE(SINHALA)","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"BUSINESS & ACCT. STUDIES","subjectResult":"A"},{"subjectName":"INFOR. & COMM. TECHNOLOGY","subjectResult":"A"}],"studentInfo":[{"param":"Examination","value":"G.C.E. (O/L) EXAMINATION"},{"param":"Year","value":"2018"},{"param":"Name","value":"NANAYAKKARA IGALA ARACHCHIGE NAVINDU THARUKA PERERA"},{"param":"Index Number","value":"80299920"},{"param":"NIC Number","value":""}]}'

result_dict = json.loads(results)

for subject in result_dict['subjectResults']:
    print('Name: ', subject['subjectName'])
    print('Result: ', subject['subjectResult'])
    print()

# prints
"""
Name:  BUDDHISM
Result:  A

Name:  SINHALA LANGUAGE & LITT.
Result:  A

Name:  ENGLISH LANGUAGE
Result:  A

Name:  MATHEMATICS
Result:  A

Name:  HISTORY
Result:  A

Name:  SCIENCE
Result:  B

Name:  DRAMA & THEATRE(SINHALA)
Result:  A

Name:  BUSINESS & ACCT. STUDIES
Result:  A

Name:  INFOR. & COMM. TECHNOLOGY
Result:  A
"""
```

Comment: An answer without explanation values nothing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import requests
import re
import time

index_number = "80299920"

URL = f'https://result.doenets.lk/result/service/OlResult?index={index_number}&nic='

while True:
    req = requests.get(URL)
    results = req.content
    if b"subjectResults" in results:
        for course in json.loads(results)['subjectResults']:
            print(f"{course['subjectResult']:2} {course['subjectName']}")
        break

    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Please give explanation, code-only answer s not worth much